# Processing millions of records from mysql in java and store the result in another database

Tags: java, mysql, mapreduce, apache-spark

- I have around 15 million records in MySQL (read only) which will be fetched using joins of 10 tables. Around 50000 new records are inserted daily. Number will keep on increasing in future.
- Each record will be processed independently by a java program. Multiple processing will be done on the same record and output will be calculated based on the processing.
- Results will be stored in another database.
- Processing shall be completed within an hour

My questions are

1. How to design the processing engine (cluster of java programs) in a distributed manner making the processing as fast as possible? To be more precise, I want to boot many spot instance at that time and finish the processing.
2. Will mysql be a read bottleneck?
3. I don't have any experience in big data solutions. Shall I use spark or any other map reduce solution? If yes, then how shall I proceed?

Comment: schema or schema-less ? this question lacks any detail necessary for a serious answer

Comment: Hi Drew, for the destination database I am thinking of using a schema-less nosql write intensive database. Most probably aerospike.

Comment: ok, then I would delete mysql from all of the above

Comment: But my source data is present in mysql.

Comment: publish a schema in text format, not some image silly thing we see too often in other questions, and spec it out

Comment: I cant publish the schema as it is internal to the company. Just assume that there is one big table which is joining 10 other tables. The size of one record will be around 5 kb.

Comment: we benchmark with real implementations, even if strawmen POCs ... not nebulous notions. I am sure you understand

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation where we were collecting about 15 million records per day. What I did was create some collection tables that I rotated and performed initial processing. Once that was done, I moved the data to the next phase where further processing was done before adding it to the large collection of data. Breaking it down will get the best performance and avoid having to run through a large set of data.

I'm not sure what you mean about processing data and why you want to do it in Java, you may have a good reason for that. I would imagine that performance would be much better if you offload that to MySQL and let it do as much of the processing as possible.

Comment: By processing the data I mean, apply some function on one or more column of the data. Store results of each function and aggregate the results based on certain weight. Taking into account the complexity of this operation, I think it would be better to do this in JAVA rather than MySQL itself.

Comment: I really don't know the details of what you're trying to do, but don't surprised at what can be done with MySQL. It is very powerful and in most cases that I've seen, much faster than looping through a bunch of records and manipulating one at a time.

Comment: Please provide a solution assuming the task cant be accomplished in mysql.

Comment: What kind of calculations/manipulation are you performing on the data? It's really hard to answer blindly. For example, we had some data that we imported from clients and we needed to add some columns that held results from operations performed on the data so that we didn't have to do it when the data was requested, so we performed the operations on the data as it was being imported. It was an additional 10 to 15 columns that were used for searching to increase performance. I don't have a solution that I can show you without knowing exactly what you want to do.